# Error says: "a running total cannot refer to a print time formula" (Crystal Reports)

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to put values in an shared array and print it to another sub report in the Details section to print each value of the array one by one.

I have Googled, yet I don't seem to get the proper answer.

Here is the code:

```
// 1st Sub Report
WhilePrintingRecords;
shared numberVar array Totdepot;

Redim preserve Totdepot[UBound(Totdepot)+1];//more space added to array.
Totdepot[UBound(Totdepot)+1]:={dtSumDe… + {dtSumDealer2.inv_depot2} + {dtSumDealer2.inv_depot3} + {dtSumDealer2.inv_depot4} + {dtSumDealer2.inv_depot5} + {dtSumDealer2.inv_depot7} + {dtSumDealer2.inv_depot6} + {dtSumDealer2.inv_depot8} + {dtSumDealer2.inv_depot9};

// 2nd Sub Report
WhilePrintingRecords;
shared numberVar array Totdepot;
Totdepot
```

I'm trying to print the second value of the array still it doesn't work. Error reads: 
"A running total cannot refer to a print time formula" or "The result of a formula cannot be an array"

Answer (score 0):

**Problem I**

The last line of your two formulas can not be an array; change it to resemble:

```
// 1st Sub Report
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar Array Totdepot;

Redim preserve Totdepot[UBound(Totdepot)+1];//more space added to array.
Totdepot[UBound(Totdepot)+1]:={dtSumDe… + {dtSumDealer2.inv_depot2} + {dtSumDealer2.inv_depot3} + {dtSumDealer2.inv_depot4} + {dtSumDealer2.inv_depot5} + {dtSumDealer2.inv_depot7} + {dtSumDealer2.inv_depot6} + {dtSumDealer2.inv_depot8} + {dtSumDealer2.inv_depot9};

// return a dummy value to eliminate array-error message
True;

// 2nd Sub Report
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar Array Totdepot;

// return a dummy value to eliminate array-error message
True;
```

**Problem II**

You won't be able to display the array in the same way that a database record is displayed; Crystal Reports will NOT generate a Details-section record for each element in the array.  It's not designed to do so.

You have two options:

- Create a formula field that will loop through the array and create a comma-delimited (or other character) string.
- Push the calculation to the database so that it will return a useable dataset.

Comment: The details section i was taking about is the details section in crystal reports that when you put a column name from a dataset, it loops through the columns and displays whatever values it has in the database.